# Как разместить или нарисовать эту линию на сайте?

Tags: javascript, html, css

В макете была эта черная линия,что на заднем плане,но я не знаю как ее разместить,буду благодарен за помощь (P.s эта линия обведена на скрине синим бордером)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: background'ом удобнее будет, хотя можно и в html вложить картинку..и на absolute  поставить куда угодно